# Jquery almost same function different selectors

Tags: jquery, function

Is there a possibility to write it a lot shorter? I don't know how to put other id's insite of the functions:

```
$("#TalkClick").click(function() {

    $("#talk").animate({
            left: 0,
          }, 1000,"swing", function() {

          });
});
$("#HectariaClick").click(function() {

    $("#hectaria").animate({
            left: 0
          }, 1000,"swing", function() {

          });
});
```

as you can see functions are the same, but with different id's inside. Is there a possibility to write one function and then just parse selectors to it?

Comment: Create one function and pass the selectors as arguments.

Comment: *"Is there a possibility to write one function and then just parse selectors to it?"* Yes, of course. Or use DOM traversal inside the event handler, if possible (depends on the relation between those elements). If you don't know how to define functions that accepts arguments, have a look at a [**JavaScript tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: These type of questions seem more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Make a reusable function, and then play around:

```
function animatorFunc( parentId , childId ) {


$(parentId).click(function() {

    $(childId).animate({
            left: 0
          }, 1000,"swing", function() {

          });
});

};
```

Now just pass along the variables:

```
animatorFunc("#TalkClick" , "#talk" );
animatorFunc("#HectariaClick" , "#hectaria" );
```

Have fun!